# C# OracleDataReader.Get???(oracle AVG()) InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, oracle, .net

I'm working in C# with an oracle database, and i have some issues with InvalidCastException when i try to data out of OracleDataReader.

The problem is the type of the function AVG().
This is the query:

```
SELECT AVG(MBAR) mbavg, AVG(ML_MIN) mlavg, RSZ FROM (SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ID, RSZ rsz2 FROM SZIVARGASMERO ORDER BY ID DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM=1 ) a, SZIVARGASMERO WHERE RSZ=a.RSZ2 GROUP BY RSZ;
```

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SZIVARGASMERO
(
  ID          NUMBER                            NOT NULL,
  RSZ         VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  CIKKSZ      VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
  DATE_G      DATE,
  DEV_ID      INTEGER,
  PROG        INTEGER,
  RES         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  REG1        INTEGER,
  MBAR        FLOAT(126),
  FE          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  REG2        INTEGER,
  ML_MIN      FLOAT(126),
  TIMESTAMPA  DATE,
  ERROR       INTEGER
)
```

I tried

```
double mbavg=reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("mbavg"));
float mbavg=reader.GetFloat(reader.GetOrdinal("mbavg"));
```

And also

```
string mbavg=reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("mbavg"));
```

And i tried parse double with CultureInvariant and System.Conver.ToXXX too, but none of them works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
//using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
....

public const string oradb ="....";
public OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
...
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT AVG(MBAR) mbavg, AVG(ML_MIN) mlavg, RSZ FROM (SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ID, RSZ rsz2 FROM SZIVARGASMERO ORDER BY ID DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM=1 ) a, SZIVARGASMERO WHERE RSZ=a.RSZ2 GROUP BY RSZ";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {

                       // double mbavg = dr.GetDouble(0);
                        double mlavg = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("mlavg"));
                        string last_rsz = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("RSZ"));
                       // mbaravg.Text = System.Convert.ToString(mbavg) + " mbar";
                        mlavg_lb.Text = System.Convert.ToString(mlavg) + " ml/min";
                        last_rsz_lb.Text = last_rsz;
                    }
                }
                dr.Dispose();
                dr.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    oracle_lb.Text = "OK";
                    ora_lbl_2.Text = "Oracle: OK!";
                    ora_lbl_2.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nincs adatbáziskapcsolat!");
                }
```

Who could i solve it? Please help me. Thank you very much :)

**Edit:**

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TRUNC(AVG(MBAR),6) mbavg, TRUNC(AVG(ML_MIN),6) mlavg, RSZ FROM (SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ID, RSZ rsz2 FROM SZIVARGASMERO ORDER BY ID DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM=1 ) a, SZIVARGASMERO WHERE RSZ=a.RSZ2 GROUP BY RSZ";

decimal mbavg_d=dr.GetDecimal(GetOrdinal("mbavg"));

double mbavg=(double)mbavg_d
```

Comment: Can you try to see what data type the field is by using [`dr.GetFieldType(dr.GetOrdinal("mlavg"))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getfieldtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Does the output of the SQL have null value for any of the fields you are doing an average on?

Comment: What is the value of `reader.GetOrdinal("mbavg")` exactly when you debut it?

Comment: I don't know how to use properly GetFieldType. I tried it, but if i debug it i can't see the value of it.

If i run the query in Toad, the value of mbavg is 461,868421052632 (maybe the problem is the decimal COMMA) but i also tried Double.Parse...

Comment: GetOrdinal's value is 0, i also tried every method without GetOrdinal and using 0

Comment: Have you tried .GetValue(dr.getordinal(...))? Should return as an object and the debugger may then tell you the type it sees the objdct as? Doing a convert.toxxx(...) around the object should then work.

Comment: System.Convert.ToDouble(GetValue...) throws OverflowException, but i succed to get the type of it, ( Type a=dr.GetFieldType(...) ) and it's System.Decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a problem with Oracle's "NUMBER" datatype. It is closely *related* to Decimal, but it may have many more digits. I recommend to truncate the result of AVG, e.g.

```
 TRUNC(AVG(MBAR), 6)
```